# How to select right ram module for MB Asrock Wolfdale 1333-D667

Tags: memory, ddr2, ecc

## Detailed

[Here is](http://valid.canardpc.com/show_oc.php?id=2338468) my system specs. (For motherboard details, [click here](http://www.asrock.com/mb/overview.asp?Model=Wolfdale1333-D667))

I want to upgrade my systems memory.

[image]

As you see on item specs page, this mainboard supports non-ECC, un-buffered memory.

## Questions

Now, I got a question about this mainboard:

- What if I buy a 2GB 240-pin DDR2 PC3200 400MHz ECC REG RAM module ? Will mainboard support this? I mean, will the mainboard support ECC memory modules? Please explain why you think so.
- What about 2GB 240-pin DDR2 PC5300 667MHz non-ECC memory?
- Explain to me what the difference between non ECC and ECC memory modules is.

Comment: Please specify the make and model number of the RAM instead of linking to an eBay auction. Secondly, to make this question more useful, please specify which specifications of the RAM module you're concerned about. Otherwise, this becomes a _"will this specific memory module work with this specific mobo?"_ -type question, which is far too localized IMO.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You **can** use error-correcting code (ECC) memory in a non-ECC motherboard. Obviously, the error correction functionality won't work.

   However, the first RAM modules presents two problems:

   - The RAM is also registered. It **might** work, but there's no guarantee.
   - It has only 400 MHz clock speed, which **won't be enough** for the CPUs that fit in your motherboard.
2. Perfect fit.
3. ECC memory can detect errors (such as single bit flips) that may cause a system crash or data corruption.

   For more information, I suggest you read the Wikipedia article [ECC memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory).

Comment: Oh.. really confused. Answer 1 says there is no chance that 1st link will work. You say it will work. 2nd 2x more expensive then 1st.

Comment: I just said that ECC memory in general will work. The first RAM module is registered and too slow. So no, it will **not** work.

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu My bad, I confused ECC and registered RAM. Dennis is correct, ECC memory will work in a non-ECC motherboard, the error correction will simply be disabled.

Comment: What about this one http://goo.gl/mv1ku ? Or, please look at this search result http://goo.gl/kgJIq (Select Azerbaijan if the shipping window will pop up) . Please advice some 1x 2gb memory module with MINIMUM price that fit with this MB. Thx in advance

Comment: The first memory is fast enough, but it is registered (REG). It might work, it might not. Any 240-pin DDR2 memory with sufficient clock speed that is not registered will do. What CPU do you have?

Comment: I updated my question, Please take a look

Comment: I re-edited question. Here is my system specs http://valid.canardpc.com/show_oc.php?id=2338468

Comment: Your CPU has a rated FSB of `800 MHz`. But since your motherboard cannot handle more than `677 Mhz` RAM, you can buy `677 MHz` or faster RAM (whatever is cheaper).

Comment: Final question: http://goo.gl/tnfEb vs http://goo.gl/8lb8L .  Registered thing confusing me a bit. Can you please explan difference between this rams? Second fit I think

Comment: The second one will work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3173/discussion-between-tural-teyyuboglu-and-dennis)